# how to use ffmpeg to cache a stream

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

i am using the following command to copy a live stream and restream it to a different endpoint. This works Ok , but the problem is that the stream breaks up/buffer occurs on client/stuttering and does not run smoothly or even fails. 
Here is the command i am using

```
ffmpeg -loglevel fatal -fflags +igndts -re -i "$1" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -tune zerolatency -f mpegts pipe:1
```

$1 is an mpegts http stream url

what will be the correct command to use for ffmpeg to "cache" few seconds of the input stream (input is mpegts) before emitting the stream out as is ? I hope by caching i can get a smooth playback , no stuttering or buffering on the client side.

thanks for help!!

Comment: I know the question is a bit old but have you found a solution? i have a similar problem

Comment: Is ffmpeg's cache protocol useful here? https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#cache

By specifying your input like "cache:https://-your-media-url" should cache a copy of the media to disk to speed up future seeks for the same content.